# Org-Babel Unable to Tangle to Write-Protected Folders?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, spacemacs, org-babel

I'm trying to move my OS configuration over to org mode, and in the process I'd like to be able to tangle to write-protected directories like /etc

Unfortunately, tangle doesn't seem to work whenever the target file needs elevated permissions. So for instance, using `org-babel-tangle` works on this code block

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :tangle psmouse.conf
options psmouse synaptics_intertouch=1
#+END_SRC
```

but trying to tangle this one will ask me for my password (which I can give just fine) and then promptly fail

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :tangle /sudo::/etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.conf
options psmouse synaptics_intertouch=1
#+END_SRC
```

The error message I get in the minibuffer says

```
Copying directly failed. See buffer '*tramp/sudo root@pop-os*' for details
```

But the weird part is, although the buffer mentioned above is created on error, it's actually empty.

My *Messages* buffer is a little bit more informative as to what's going on

```
Setting up indent for shell type bash
Indentation variables are now local.
Indentation setup for shell type bash
Copying /tmp/tramp.l6Xnsw.conf to /sudo:root@pop-os:/etc/modeprobe.d/psmouse.conf...failed
tramp-error: Copying directly failed, see buffer ‘*tramp/sudo root@pop-os*’ for details.
```

Comment: Did you try using the `:dir /sudo:root@pop-os:/etc/modeprobe.d  :tangle psmouse.conf :session *my-session*` ?

Comment: Just tried it: it removes the error ("1 block tangled successfully from file.org") but, weirdly, doesn't actually create the specified file

Comment: That is weird. I’m going to guess the tangle put the file in ~root/ directory. If so, please try updating `:tangle /etc/modeprobe.d :mkdirp yes` and tangle again please.

Comment: The original format you suggested actually just tangles to `~/Desktop`, which is where the relevant org file is located. Tangling with `#+BEGIN_SRC sh :dir etc/modeprobe.d :tangle psmouse.conf :mkdirp yes` also just tangles to the desktop

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Did the file still tangle as root user even though it was on Desktop? If so then we just need to troubleshoot the `:tangle` path.

Comment: My own turn to apologize for the delay. I just revisited the problem, and my issue was a misspelling of the path I wanted to tangle to. I typo'd "modprobe" and "modeprobe" (this is actually visible in the error message I posted, meaning that I must not have actually tried to tangle the "sudo" block I posted since that's spelled right), and didn't pass the ":mkdirp yes" flag. A more informative error message might have been nice, but the fault is mine. Thank you for your help and patience, and sorry for wasting your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of the error ended up being a spelling mistake on my part. See my comments on the question. Thanks to @Melioratus for their help!